# How can I join 2 pandas dataframe using left join?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have 2 dataframes which I need to join using left join. In sql I have the query as

```sql
SELECT A.* INTO NewTable FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.id=B.id WHERE B.id IS NULL;
```

I have the 2 dataframes as:
df1:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | one |
| 2 | two |
| 3 | three |
| 4 | four |

df2:

| id |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |

**What I am expecting is:**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | one |
| 4 | four |

**What I have tried?**

```py
common = df1.merge(df2, on=['id', 'id'])
result = df1[~df1.id.isin(common.id)]
```

I get more results in this then what the query returns. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you have the right solution,only you do interpret the results wrong.

This will give you the result without index

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'id': [1, 2,3,4], 'col2': ['one','two','three','four']}
d1 = {'id': [2,3]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df2 =  pd.DataFrame(data=d1)


result = df1[~df1.id.isin(df2.id)]
print(result.to_string(index=False))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use left join with [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `indicator=` parameter turned on. Then, filter the indicator values equal to `"left_only"` with [`.query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), as follows:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='left', indicator='ind').query('ind == "left_only"')
```

**Result:**

```
   id  name        ind
0   1   one  left_only
3   4  four  left_only
```

Optionally, you can remove the indicator column, as follows:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='left', indicator='ind').query('ind == "left_only"').drop('ind', axis=1)
```

**Result:**

```
   id  name
0   1   one
3   4  four
```

Comment: The thing that is throwing me off is when I run the query I get less number of records and with the pandas approach I am getting more records.

Comment: @ChinwalPrasad  You mean SQL query or the `.query()` in my code ?    Do my codes give you correct result ?

Comment: So what I mean is when I run the sql query I get around 2200 records. But when I use your method my dataframe has around 6600 records.

Comment: @ChinwalPrasad  Just want to double check with you what's your intended result.  You want to get the filtered rows that is from `df1` AND at the same remove those rows from `df1` if the rows have the `id` also appear in `df2`.  Is this correct ?    If yes, do you see from the 6600 records any rows from `df2` that should have been removed but was  failed to remove ?

Comment: @ChinwalPrasad  Would it be that your `df2` has other column(s) with the same column label as `df1` ?    If yes, please use my edited code above.  Amended to add `on='id'` during the merge in order to explicitly match only the `id` column.  The old code was based on your sample data which does not have other columns in `df2`.    Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
print(df1[~df1["id"].isin(df2["id"])])
```

Prints:

```py
   id  name
0   1   one
3   4  four
```

Comment: Unfortunately same result with this method.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, "one"], [2, "two"], [3, "three"], [4, "four"]]),
                   columns=['id', 'name '])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1], [2]]),
                   columns=['id'])
```

---

```
df1.drop(df2['id'], axis=0,inplace=True)
df1
```

[image]